# Highcharts, change line type if more than one series on the chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

With a highcharts chart, is it possible to set the line type if there is more than 1 series in the chart, could this be set in the theme?

Basically I was thinking something like having:

```
var lineType = 'area';
```

And then in the chart options something like this:

```
chart: { type: lineType }
```

What's the best way of knowing how many series are in the chart? Then I'm guessing I would need some kind of if statement to know how many series there were, and set the lineType variable accordingly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have container for a series, something like this:

```
var series = [{}, {}, {}];
```

And then you can try something like this when creating chart:

```
new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'div'
    type: series.length > 5 ? 'line' : 'column'
  }, 
  // rest of optipons
  series: series
}
```

Comment: hmmm, i get an error saying series is not defined, thanks for your help

Comment: Have you defined `series` as I did? I mean, you have to put series into another variable, to use that solution.

Comment: ah ok, no our series will be coming from a database, and we're using highstock, not sure if this is a problem?

Comment: I don't think so - the same way it will work for Highstock. If you are using something like $.getJSON(), so you have access to your data.series.length (or something similar). If you can show sample data from database in Javascript you have, I could tell more.